# Displaying results in c++

Tags: visual-c++

I have a question concerning working with classes in c++. I must say I'm a beginner. For example, i have this class:

```
class student {
    private:
        char* name;
    public:
        int nrcrt;
        student() {
            name = new char[7];
            name = "Anonim";
            nrcrt = 0;
        }
        student(char* n, int n) {
            this->name = new char[7];
            strcpy(name, n);
            nrcrt = nr;
        }
        ~student() {
            delete [] name;
        }
        char* get_name() {
            return this->name;
        }
}

void main() {
   student group[3];
   group[0] = student("Ana", 1);
   group[1] = student("Alex", 2);
   group[2] = student("Liam", 5);

   for (i=0; i<3; i++) {
       if (group.nrcrt[i] != 0) 
           cout << group[i].get_name() << Endl;
   }
}
```

My question is why is it displaying different characters?

Comment: The code doesn't compile.

Comment: Welcome to SO. We are not a site that debug your code instead of you. What are you trying to achieve, and what is the problem concerning what you wanted to achieve ? Show us your effort, and most probably we will help you.

Comment: @AntonSavin maybe   
    `group[i].nrcrt `
and not 
    `group.nrcrt[i]`

Comment: I'm sorry. When I wrote it here, i made that mistake. In

Comment: @Mada what about `student( char* n, int n)`?

Answer (score 0):

first of all your code is not working.

```
3.cpp:40:18: error: request for member ‘nrcrt’ in ‘group’, which is of non-class type      ‘student [3]’
     if(group.nrcrt[i]!=0)
```

i is also not declared.please make proper changes.

```
 group.nrcrt[i]
```

should be changed to:

```
group[i].nrcrt
```

Answer (score 0):

do not worry. C++ could look a bit scary as first but it is ok when you get into it. First, let's say that all classes it is good to start with upper case letters. Secondly, you have two constructors (default without parameters and one or more with, in our case one). Default consructor you need to declare an array of objects:

```
Student group[3];
```

The next important thing is that you then do not need the rest of the constructors in that case.

```
group[0]=student("Ana",1);
group[1]=student("Alex",2);
group[2]=student("Liam",5);
```

Remember to include ; at the end of class declaration. To put all the statements and expression throughout your interation within the same loop. Here is what I found as an errors anf fix them. Could probably have more.

```
class Student
{
    private:
        char* name;
public:
    int nrcrt;
Student()
{
    name=new char[7];
    strcpy(name, "Anonim");
    nrcrt=0;
}
Student( char* n, int n)
{
    this->name=new char[7];
    strcpy(name, n);
    nrcrt=nr;
}
~Student()
{
    delete [] name;
}

char* get_name()
{
    return this->name;
}

};
int main()
{
    Student group[3];

 for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
 {   
    if(group.nrcrt[i]!=0)
        cout<<group[i].get_name()<<endl;
 } 
  return 0;  
}
```

Comment: The point is when I want to display a pointer to char , it appears on the screen something like 'îăîăîăîîă'. Regarding the program wrote with errors, it was more an example I wrote it in a rush to explain the problem. I'm sorry.

Comment: Yes, because you are assigning in the default constructor:

name = "Anton"...
No, once you use new operator, you must copy the data with strcpy.

Comment: "First, let's say that all classes must start with upper case letters" Mhh... **no, this is not a C++ rule**. If you leave this sentence, I may put you -1 during the day. Edit plz.

Comment: Correct. Let's say it is good to start. Must is a strong word.

Answer (score 0):

When the array is created, your default constructor is used.
When you assign to the elements, your destructor is called, deleting `name`.
The default constructor is assigning a literal to `name`, and deleting that memory has undefined behaviour.

In your default constructor, replace

```
name = "Anonim";
```

with

```
strcpy(name, "Anonim");
```

Your compiler should have warned you about the assignment.
If it didn't, increase the warning level of your compiler.
If it did, start listening to your compiler's warnings.

Comment: Still the same problem.

Comment: @Mada Post some actual code that exhibits the behaviour. Make sure it compiles and runs.